# SSIS: How to aggregate parent-child in script block?

Tags: .net, xml, ssis

I've got an XML Source that I'm importing in SSIS.

Here's a snippet:

```
  <pmd:TAG>
    <pmd:Folder>Something</pmd:Folder>
    <pmd:Index>Index1</pmd:Index>
    <pmd:Index>Index2</pmd:Index>
    <pmd:Index>Index3</pmd:Index>
    <pmd:Index>Index4</pmd:Index>
  </pmd:TAG>
```

Don't get me started about the XSD for this ... but I have to deal with it and it's not going to change. What I want to do with this is have a script tag that will call:

```
SomeClass.DoSomething("Something", "Index1", "Index2", "Index3", "Index4");
```

I created that class, and it's in the GAC.

If I create a script block from the XML source, I can select the TAG element as input, which gives me only access to the Folder value, if I edit the script and inspect the Row instance.

There is another input that I can choose for the script, which is called TAG_Index which has an TAG_Id and the index value.

Ideally I'd do something like:

```
var indexes = Row.Indexes.ToArray();
SomeClass.DoSomething(Row.Folder, indexes)
```

The indexes parameter has param - so an array will do.

Point is - how do I get access to TAG 'child' items from the parent?

I tried a union - but that will give me a resultset like:

```
+------------+--------+
|   Folder   | Value  |
+------------+--------+
| Something  | Index1 |
| Something  | Index2 |
| Something  | Index3 |
| Something  | Index4 |
+------------+--------+
```

Which I cannot import with the Script block either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you `PIVOT` the resultset into a single row?  It's not elegant, but it might work.

Comment: Thanks - I'll look into that. For now, I'm experiencing this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25661709/ssis-xml-datasource-unbounded-elements-are-null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this issue by transforming the data using an XML task and XSLT. Before:

```
<Tag>
  <Folder>Whatever</Folder>
  <Index>2014-03-31</Index>
  <Index>31454534</Index>
  <Index>3274</Index>
  <Index>Testname1 Testname2</Index>
</Tag>
```

After:

```
<Tags>
  <Tag Folder="Whatever" Index1="2014-03-31" Index2="31454534" Index3="3274" Index4="Testname1 Testname2" />
</Tags>
```

XSLT is below ( I got rid of all names and stuff, so this is not a working example ). We run the transform from the XML task ( as described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattm/archive/2007/12/15/xml-source-making-things-easier-with-xslt.aspx ). We save the result into a variable. Then we run a data-flow task with an XML source that loads the XML from the variable. Then all the rows DO appear. We then use this as input for our script-component where we have access to: Row.Folder, Row.Index1 ... etc.

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:pmd="http://something"
                xmlns:default="http://something"
                xmlns:k="http://something"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <k:TagList>
      <k:Tags>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </k:Tags>
    </k:TagList>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="default:Metadata">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="pmd:Tag">
    <k:Tag>
      <xsl:attribute name="Folder">
        <xsl:value-of select="pmd:Folder" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="Index1">
        <xsl:value-of select="pmd:Index[1]" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="Index2">
        <xsl:value-of select="pmd:Index[2]" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="Index3">
        <xsl:value-of select="pmd:Index[3]" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="Index4">
        <xsl:value-of select="pmd:Index[4]" />
      </xsl:attribute>
    </k:Tag>
  </xsl:template>
```